# Run-time error 8000fff on VBA CreateObject

Tags: vba, excel, rhino3d

As a follow-up to a previous post about my VBA/Rhinoscript, I'm running to a really weird "catastrophic" error when I execute the following VBA code from an Excel spreadsheet originally created in Excel 2007 that I'm now trying to run in Excel 2016:

```
Set Rhino = CreateObject("Rhino4.Interface")
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    'MsgBox ("Failed to create Rhino4 object")
    Set Rhino = CreateObject("Rhino4.Application")
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        MsgBox "Failed to create Rhino4 object: " & Err.Number
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

The `CreateObject` failing with a `Run-time error 8000fff Automation error, Catastrophic failure.`  Checking around, people have made vague mentions of about migrating between Excel versions being a problem and to look under Tools->References, but I'm not sure exactly what I should be looking for.  Does anyone know?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rhinoscript but people are basically saying it is an external reference that Excel can't resolve by default. In the VBA editor go Tools>References and ensure whatever dependencies there are for Rhinoscript are ticked and/or included. My guess is these were set up in the previous Excel version but not the new version.

Comment: I checked and saw nothing "MISSING".  It doesn't crash if Rhino is already running (though Excel won't speak to it).  And as far as I know, nothing in the external access docs regarding Rhino say I have to specifically use an add-in.  It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make your code work here with Excel 2010 and Rhino 4.0 SR9.

If you are not running Rhino 4.0 SR9, then I suggest you download and install this service release:

http://www.rhino3d.com/download/rhino/4.0/sr

My guess is that Rhino's COM components are not property registered (in the Windows Registry). Installing the latest service release should fix this.

Let me now if this helps.

-- Dale